# postgresql: group by in column update - syntax error

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sql-update, postgis

I'm trying to get the altitude of the heighest point in each area, I wrote this query which in working fine:

```
select max(obstacle.valhgt_ft) 
from obstacle,
     obstacle_buffer 
where st_contains (obstacle_buffer.geom,obstacle.geom) 
group by obstacle_buffer.primary_id
```

But when I try to update an attribute with this query I have a syntax error near "group"

```
UPDATE obstacle_buffer 
    SET max_valhgt_ft = max(obstacle.valhgt_ft) 
from obstacle,
     obstacle_buffer 
where st_contains (obstacle_buffer.geom,obstacle.geom) 
group by obstacle_buffer.primary_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a co-related sub-query to do this:

```
UPDATE obstacle_buffer 
    SET max_valhgt_ft = (select max(obstacle.valhgt_ft) 
                         from obstacle 
                         where st_contains (obstacle_buffer.geom, obstacle.geom))
```

Answer (score 0):

you tried to update join table and it's not allowed you should use subquery instead

you can do this

```
UPDATE obstacle_buffer 
SET max_valhgt_ft = (select max(obstacle.valhgt_ft) 
                     from obstacle,obstacle_buffer 
                     where st_contains (obstacle_buffer.geom,obstacle.geom) 
                     group by obstacle_buffer.primary_id)
```

Comment: `max_valhgt_ft` is from wich table?

Comment: There is no need to repeat the `obstacle_buffer` table in the sub-query